# Adding up values before deleting redundant entries

Tags: sql, oracle, delete-row, insert-update

I have a data set like the following:

```
Identifier | Revenue | Good Inflow
-----------------------------------
  abc123   |   20    |  15
  abc124   |   10    |   5
  abc124   |    5    |   5
```

As you can see there are two lines with the same identifier, different revenue but the same (redundant) good inflow. What I want to achieve is to eliminate the second line with the same identifier but to add the revenue to the revenue of the first line. Hence the result should be:

```
abc124 | 15 | 5
```

Is this possible? If so which command do I need? I use Oracle SQL Developer.

Thank you in advance!

Felix

Comment: Please show your table data as formatted text, not an image. Are those the only three columns in your table? Do you only need to combine that specific pair of rows (which you can do with a simple update and delete using the specific value), or do you have lots of similar pairs that need to be combined?

Comment: Do you want this as a SELECT query or as a delete statement?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Question is, if that is indeed the requirement (to change data in the table, and not simply to group the data for a report) - is that a good practice? In my opinion, in most cases that is a poor practice. One can write views (and MVs if needed for performance) for analysis and reporting purposes, but the base data should be left alone.

Comment: @mathguy - yes, agree. I assumed (always dangerous) this is a clean-up operation on the base data. The title says 'delete', but as the question says 'eliminate' it may just be a query/view rather than an actual update/delete. They may just want an aggregate result set.

Comment: @AlexPoole It's quite a bit of data (around 400,000 lines), however not all of them need to be aggregated like described. As you pointed out I need an aggregate result set. I will try your solution, thanks for your help!

Comment: @FelixBrehmer - I've updated it to avoid updating the rows that don't have duplicates or need aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a merge. With a dummy table to simulate your data:

```
create table t42 (identifier varchar2(10), revenue number, good_inflow number);
insert into t42 values ('abc123', 20, 15);
insert into t42 values ('abc124', 10, 5);
insert into t42 values ('abc124', 5, 5);
```

you can use analytic functions to get the total as an extra column against each row, along with a pseudo row number:

```
select t42.*,
  sum(revenue) over (partition by identifier, good_inflow) as total_revenue,
  row_number() over (partition by identifier, good_inflow order by rowid) as rn,
  count(*) over (partition by identifier, good_inflow) as cnt
from t42;

IDENTIFIER REVENUE GOOD_INFLOW TOTAL_REVENUE   RN  CNT
---------- ------- ----------- ------------- ---- ----
abc123          20          15            20    1    1
abc124          10           5            15    1    2
abc124           5           5            15    2    2
```

You can then use that as the `using` clause of a `merge` statement, adding the `rowid` of the underlying table as the `on` condition, and using the generated `cnt` to only update those that have duplicates (so any ID/inflow pair that only appears once isn't pointlessly updated to the same value):

```
merge into (select t42.*, rowid from t42) t42
using (
  select t42.*, rowid,
    sum(revenue) over (partition by identifier, good_inflow) as total_revenue,
    row_number() over (partition by identifier, good_inflow order by rowid) as rn,
    count(*) over (partition by identifier, good_inflow) as cnt
  from t42
) tmp
on (tmp.rowid = t42.rowid and tmp.cnt > 1)
when matched then
  update set revenue = case when tmp.rn = 1 then tmp.total_revenue else null end
delete where (revenue is null);

2 rows merged.
```

The `delete` clause works on the post-update value; I've used the case expression to set the revenue to null for all but the nominal first row for each combination. Those will null can now be deleted.

```
select * from t42;

IDENTIFIER REVENUE GOOD_INFLOW
---------- ------- -----------
abc123          20          15
abc124          15           5
```

However, this does assume the revenue value can't be null anyway. If it is nullable then it can be adapted to deal with that.